# trying to sum two strings and store the result in another string?

Tags: c, string

I was trying to sum two strings together, this is my attempt:

- convert strings to numbers using strtol, because it's safer than atoi.
- compute sum.
- find number of digits using log (base 10) rounded using floor + 1. (it's the fastest method to do that task). (I've used floor, because floor rounds number to the nearest integer at the left hand side).
- I've allocated enough memory in the heap to store each digit.
- I've used snprintf to store the number in the string.

the problem is that the function returns only "4", and not "42". I think the delicate part is the last step.

another thing is: "possible loss of data: from double to size_t". but it's rounded, therefore it shouldn't be a problem, but I still have it in the error/warning list. (I use visual studio).

---

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char* sum_of_strings(const char* a, const char* b) {
    int x = strtol(a, NULL, 10); int y = strtol(b, NULL, 10); 
    int sum = x + y; 
    size_t length = floor(log10(sum)) + 1; 
    char* str = malloc(length +1); 
    if (str == NULL) {
        return NULL; 
    }
    snprintf(str, length, "%d", sum); 
    return str; 
}    



int main(void) {
    char a[] = "34"; 
    char b[] = "8";
    char* str = sum_of_strings(a, b); 

    free(str); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Since you're allocating `length + 1` bytes you should also use `length + 1` for the buffer length in `snprintf`.

Comment: Or change the length calculation to `floor(log10(sum)) + 1;` to account for the null byte.

Comment: I was going to tell you to should make sure "str" is not NULL before you free it, but apparently you can safely call free with a NULL pointer (it does nothing in that case). I still recommend checking, because you might decide to print "str" or use it in some other way, in which case, you will need to remember to add the check.

Comment: Do the inputs and outputs all fit into an `int`? If not, this won't suffice. And may they be negative? If not, the round-trip-conversion is inefficient...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your `sum_of_strings` code and it seems to now be working based on your example.

Changes include the following:

- Data types are now longs instead of ints
- I've added two bytes to the length to account for the floor and the null byte
- The last byte of the string is set to the null byte which makes printing work correctly

```
char* sum_of_strings(const char* a, const char* b) {
    long const x = strtol(a, NULL, 10);
    long const y = strtol(b, NULL, 10);
    long const sum = x + y;
    size_t const length = floor(log10(sum)) + 2;
    char * const str = malloc(length);
    if (str == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    snprintf(str, length, "%ld", sum);
    str[length - 1] = '\0';
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You may be overthinking the problem.

The maximum size of the output string is [considerably] less than 64 bytes.

So, if we use a fixed size buffer to do `sprintf` on, we can eliminate all the floating point rounding altogether:

```
char *
sum_of_strings(const char *a,const char *b)
{
    int x = strtol(a,NULL,10);
    int y = strtol(b,NULL,10);

    int sum = x + y;

    char str[64];
    sprintf(str, "%d", sum);

    return strdup(str);
}
```

---

The above code is pretty simple and fast.

However, `strdup` has to [effectively] scan the string twice: once to get the length and a second time to copy it to the allocated buffer.

We can [probably] make this slightly faster:

```
char *
sum_of_strings(const char *a,const char *b)
{
    long x = strtol(a,NULL,10);
    long y = strtol(b,NULL,10);

    long sum = x + y;

    char str[64];
    ssize_t len = sprintf(str, "%ld", sum);

    // add space for EOS
    ++len;

    char *ret = malloc(len);
    if (ret != NULL)
        memcpy(ret,str,len);

    return ret;
}
```

---

Rather than using floating point, the usual way to get the number of digits is something like:

```
size_t len = (sum != 0) ? 0 : 1;
for (long tmp = sum;  tmp != 0;  tmp /= 10, ++len);
```

Arguably, this *may* be slower than the floating point [on systems that have fast H/W FPUs]. I *presume* you've benchmarked *both* ways [to be able to state your F.P. method is fastest]. If not, the above may be a drop in replacement for your F.P. code.

Is `floor(log10(sum))` really faster [on average] than 5 fixed point divides?

---

But even that doesn't account for hidden costs.

`sprintf` et. al. has to do much the same when generating its output (e.g. `sum % 10` and `sum /= 10`).

If we're "crazy" for speed, and if we do our own limited version of what `sprintf` does, we can do the length calculation in the same loop as the digit stores:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXBUF  64

char *
sum_of_strings(const char *a,const char *b)
{
    long x = strtol(a,NULL,10);
    long y = strtol(b,NULL,10);

    long sum = x + y;

    char str[MAXBUF];
    char *lhs = &str[MAXBUF];

    // store digits in right-to-left order
    for (;  sum != 0;  sum /= 10)
        *--lhs = (sum % 10) + '0';

    // get number of digits
    size_t len = &str[MAXBUF] - lhs;

    // handle special case of sum being zero
    if (len == 0) {
        *--lhs = '0';
        ++len;
    }

    // allocate the space
    char *ret = malloc(len);

    // copy out the data
    if (ret != NULL) {
        memcpy(ret,lhs,len);
        ret[len] = 0;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Of course, which method is "best" depends on simplicity/complexity vs. [benchmarked] speed. That is, is added complexity for [possible] speed gains worth it?

YMMV ...